# How to use SQLAlchemy with buildozer?

Tags: android, python, sqlalchemy, kivy, buildozer

Recently buildozer has compiled a simple **"hello world"** program.

But i want to use SQLAlchemy in **main.py** file.

The file contains:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        pass

    def olustur(self):
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db', echo = True)
        cur = engine.connect()
        self.root.ids['etkt'].text = 'Bağlantı Başarılı!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Also there's a **myapp.kv** file which contains:

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        id: etkt
        text: 'Etiket'
    Button:
        text: 'Tıkla'
        on_press: app.olustur()
```

I changed the necessarry parts in buildozer.spec file:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3crystax,SQLAlchemy,kivy

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c
android.ndk = 10.3.2

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =
android.ndk_path = /opt/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
```

But it gives an error.

What i want to learn is, i should change also the part of the spec file like below or i should do a different thing?

```
# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy
  requirements.source.SQLAlchemy = .../../SQLAlchemy
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

The new output is:

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[WARNING]: NDK version was set as r10.3.2, but checking the NDK dir claims it is 10.3.2.
[WARNING]: The build will try to continue, but it may fail and you should check that your setting is correct.
[WARNING]: If the NDK dir result is correct, you don't need to manually set the NDK ver.
[INFO]:    Using Crystax NDK r10.3.2
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9', '5', 'clang3.6', 'clang3.7']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 5
[INFO]:    No existing dists meet the given requirements!
[INFO]:    No dist exists that meets your requirements, so one will be built.
[ERROR]:   Didn't find any valid dependency graphs.
[ERROR]:   This means that some of your requirements pull in conflicting dependencies.
[ERROR]:   Exiting.
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystax,sqlite3,sqlalchemy,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/tanberk/Android3/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe name is `sqlalchemy`, not `SQLAlchemy`.

I'll look at adding some kind of check or warning about the case, I haven't thought about this type of problem before.

Comment: I guess you are right. By the way recently an android apk has built by Python 2.7. In the .spec file, the requirements was written requirements = sqlite3,sqlalchemy,kivy . I will try with Python3 again.

Comment: I created a simple "hello world" program both with Python2 and Python3. But this sqlalchemy example hasn't compiled by Python3 yet. I added the requirements like the first example. ndk version is same, kivy version is same. But it gives an error. Strange. Perhaps i did something wrong which i haven't found yet.

Comment: The sqlalchemy recipe probably hasn't been tested with python3. That said, are you following [the instructions](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#python3), in particular using the CrystaX NDK?

Comment: Yes, it has written: _The python3crystax build is handled quite differently to python2 so there may be bugs or surprising behaviours. If you come across any, feel free to open an issue._

Comment: Have you been able to make a working python3 apk without sqlalchemy?

Comment: Yes, a simple "hello world" application was made with Python3.

Comment: I made two android applications compiled by Python2 which works on phone. The first one is a "hello world" app and the second is a simple sqlalchemy application. And there's a "hello world" application compiled by Python3. This works on phone too. But a simle sqlalchemy application haven't compiled by Python3 yet.

Comment: I compiled without adding sqlalchemy to the requirements but the application is not working on phone. Also adding sqlalchemy to the requirements makes the compile process terminated. Perhaps python3crystax and sqlalchemy are incompatible?

Comment: It sounds like yes, sqlalchemy may not work with python3crystax yet.

Comment: Hi, when you are free, can you look at this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038588/python-kivy-how-to-create-recipes-for-bs4-module-and-its-dependecies