# Python/Kivy: How to create recipes for bs4 module and it's dependencies?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I tried to import bs4 module to an android application.
Here are the codes:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        try:
            import bs4
            result = "Done..."
        except:
            result = "Failed..."
        return Label(text=result)


MyApp().run()
```

In order to import it, i copied the recipe files of bs4 and the necessarry libraries (lxml, libxml2, libxslt) which are written at this website:

https://github.com/yaki29/python-for-android/commit/c4b8969e3104d39535380bc07cf8c1c8f6dcd75a

I created new recipe folders in **.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/recipes** directory for bs4 and it's dependencies and then i put the `__init__.py` files to these new folders according to the above website.

And i added these libraries in requirements of the buildozer.spec file.

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = bs4, lxml, libxml2, libxslt, kivy
```

Also after the compilation failed, i changed the buildozer.spec files requirements sections like this:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = bs4, lxml, kivy
```

But, the compilation failed again.

So, i wonder whether these recipe files are complete or not.

For example, i made an example with importing html5lib to the android application.

There's any html5lib recipe file too. Therefore i wrote a recipe file that includes the below codes:

```
from pythonforandroid.toolchain import Recipe


class html5libRecipe(Recipe):
    version = '0.999999999'
    url = 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/17/ee/99e69cdcefc354e0c18ff2cc60aeeb5bfcc2e33f051bf0cc5526d790c445/html5lib-{version}.tar.gz'
    md5sum = '8578e4e3a341436cb9743a9e4a299239'
    name = 'html5lib'


recipe = html5libRecipe()
```

These codes are in `__init__.py` file. And this `__init__.py` file is in html5lib folder. I put this folder in **.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/recipes** directory. Then i changed the requirements as follows:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = html5lib, kivy
```

And finally, i compiled the main.py file. And a working application was created.

And also i observed that recipe files are not same. Some have more codes than others. I guess it depends on the library type. For example libxml2 and libxlst are C libraries. Therefore the recipe file of them are quite different than html5lib?

Hope you understand my problem.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Note: I use Python2.7, OS is Ubuntu 17.04.